# Stored Procedure can't recognize parameter. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm creating a stored procedure to insert data into three different tables.
Here is my code:

```
/*------------------------- Procedure for owner to submit his property -------------------------*/
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SubmitProperty (
    IN input_property_owner_id INT,
    IN input_property_type_id INT,
    IN input_address VARCHAR(255),
    IN input_zip_code VARCHAR(255),
    IN input_area_m2 INT,
    IN input_price_€ INT      
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO property (property_owner_id, property_type_id, address, zip_code, area_m2, price_€)
    VALUES
        (input_property_owner_id, input_property_type_id, input_address, input_zip_code, input_area_m2, input_price_€);

    INSERT INTO survey (property_id, cas_eval_id, checksum_xxx)
    VALUES
        (property.id, 'CAS-XXX-YYYY', property.id % 1000);

    INSERT INTO survey_question_answer (survey_id, question_id)
    SELECT property_type_question.question_id
    FROM property_type_question
    WHERE property_type_question.property_type_id = input_property_type_id
    VALUES
        (survey.id, property_type_question.question_id);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The first 2 inserts work properly.
However, I get an error in the 3rd insert (around the area between the very last "FROM" and "VALUES").
Here is a picture of the error message:
[image] 
Could you guys help me figure this out?
Thanks!

Comment: You have both `select where` and `values` in the same query. Pick one. Besides, the `select` part selects only one column when you are inserting into two.

Comment: Have you tried to change the parameter name?

Comment: @AderbalFarias yes I have. I think it chagned the error type, but still gave me an error.

Comment: "can't recognize parameter" is not correct. Please read exactly: "unexpected" is not the same as "unknown". It's IMHO though a bug in workbench's parser.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The `insert` query uses both a `select` clause and a `values` clause. If has to be [one or another](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). The statement is therefore malformed and the parser is correct to reject it. It may have provided better diagnostics, but diagnosing exactly what is wrong with malformed code is pretty difficult.

Comment: @GSerg But at the same time the "error message" is kind of random. I'd expect a syntax error on `VALUES` or a parse error on `FROM`. But as it is, it looks like everything is fine until `=`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE SubmitProperty` and look at the extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you're trying to insert into two columns, but are only selecting one?

```
INSERT INTO survey_question_answer (survey_id, question_id)
SELECT property_type_question.question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is survey_id an identity column? If no, you need to bring in the survey_id from survey table and add that to your select clause:

```
INSERT INTO survey_question_answer (survey_id , question_id)
SELECT survey.id, property_type_question.question_id
FROM property_type_question
//Join here with your survey table
WHERE property_type_question.property_type_id = input_property_type_id;
```